# d3 js axis Percentage Values with decimals

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 to create a graph - (still learning both of those). I'd like my Y-axis to display values in percentages. The min and max values on the Y-axis are allocated dynamically, so the axis scale could sometimes be `25% to 38%` or sometimes even `13% to 16%`.

When there is a relatively larger range such as `25% to 28%`, I'm fine with the numbers appearing as they are, i.e. `25%, 28%, 31% ....`

However, for a really small range, I notice it appears as `13%, 14%, 14%, 15%, 15%,...` (numbers repeating, probably because behind the scenes they might be something like say, `14.2%` and `14.8%`).
In such cases, I'd like the numbers to appear with 1 decimal place specified, such as `13.5%`.

I know I can specify

```
.tickFormat(d3.format(".1%"))
```

and this gives me what I need in that case. The problem is when I have a larger scale, it essentially gives me `25.0%, 28.0%, 31.0%,...` and in this case, I'd like no decimal precision.

Is there a simple way I can handle each scenario? Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Well, one easy way would be to specify the tick format depending on the tick range. You check if the range is big enough, and add the decimal point format or not depending on that.

Comment: @nem035 True, I did think about that. But the way I see it, I'd have to obtain the range, check if it was large enough and accordingly assign the format to a variable and then feed it to the tickFormat. And while that isn't horrible by any means, I was wondering if there was some direct format which would use a decimal place when applicable and none when 0. Thank you so much though :)

Comment: Check out my answer for a direct way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could check if the range is big enough and add the decimal point format depending on that but that wouldn't be very clean. I suggest you pass your own function as the `tickFormat` that applies the format depending if the value has a decimal portion or not. Something like:

```
// defined your formatters somewhere above
var decimalFormatter = d3.format(".1");

myAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { 
  if (!Number.isInteger(d)) {
    d = decimalFormatter(d); // add the decimal point for non-integers
  }
  return d + '%';
}
```

Sample code:

```js
// defined your formatters somewhere above
var decimalFormatter = d3.format(".1");

var tickFormat = function(d) { 
  if (!Number.isInteger(d)) {
    d = decimalFormatter(d); // add the decimal point for non-integers
  }
  return d + '%';
};

console.log(tickFormat(12.5)); // 12.5%
console.log(tickFormat(14));   // 14%
console.log(tickFormat(15));   // 15%
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Where you can adjust the function above in any specific way you might need. For example, if you are using strings instead of numbers, you will need to first convert to a number and then use `Number.isInteger` because it will always return `false` for a string.

Comment: Not trying to be tough here, I promise - The numbers I'll have will always be large decimals like 0.324534, 0.432567 which could then be converted to 32% and 43%, for instance. When the gap is large, it doesn't matter. The problem occurs when its a really small range like [0.143567,0.175432] because then the tick values repeat without showing additional decimal places. I'm going to go ahead with your first suggestion though (the one in the comment), since there doesn't seem to be a more direct way out. Accepting as an answer, thank you once again!

Comment: Well then your formatting depends on the entire range and not individual numbers, meaning you might need to go for my initial suggested way

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to go ahead and try your edit right now as well

Comment: No worries, glad to help if I can :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the solution for numbers of a small scale: `d3.format(.1%)`. For numbers of a large scale, you can use `d3.format(~%)`. This will automatically delete the trailing zero for, say, `25.0%, 28.0%, 31.0%,...`

The [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#d3-format) of d3-format mentions that:

> The `~` option trims insignificant trailing zeros across all format types. This is most commonly used in conjunction with types `r`, `e`, `s` and `%`.